# Why are STL's iterators exposing their container's internals? Why are iterator's member variables mostly public?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, encapsulation

`std::list`'s `iterator` is a `struct`, not a `class`.

In some implementations, it has the node pointer public and accessible to the user. Therefore, a user should be able to "accidentally" modify a link and break the relationships within the list through an iterator. Why is this possible?

I do get that the member functions of containers (the ones that modify the container) frequently need to extract the underlying pointers from the iterators, but can't the container itself be a `friend` to the iterator? And the internals of it [the iterator] be declared `private`?

Doesn't this violate encapsulation and OOP principles?

Can you explain the logic behind this decision? Why doesn't the standard require the iterators' internals to be `private`?

Comment: Pretty sure the spec doesn't specify any of that. A given compiler author might have implemented it that way, but that doesn't mean you can rely on any of it.

Comment: where did you take this information from? Afaik you are talking about implementation details while `std::list::iterator` is only specified to be a LegacyBirederticionalIterator

Comment: btw the difference between `struct` and `class` is purely cosmetic. It determines the default accessibility of members, but either of the two can have all members private or all public or anything in between

Comment: in other words, C++ does not have structs and classes. It has classes and `struct` and `class` are just two keywords that can be used to declare a class

Comment: What you're looking at is implementation specific (stl from msvc uses a class without private members). The standard only specifies iterator behavior not implementation.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to an example.  Here is the MSVC STL for list iterators https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/17fde2cbab6e8724d81c9555237c9a623d7fb954/stl/inc/list#L131  Note the use of `class`

Comment: why doesn't the standard require the members of iterators to be `private`? wouldn't that be better? any pros or cons on this? I updated the post to include this question

Comment: @Mampac Standard requires that certain operations can be performed on the object. That's it. How it is done and how it is implemented is purely up to implementation, standard doesn't care.

Comment: @Mampac The Standard does not specify the implementation only the required observable behaviour.

Comment: the standard specifies what is necessary to use it as iterator, not more. If you write code that relies on implementation details then that is your fault. C++ isnt the language with the philosophy to protect from the most dumbest user.

Comment: The C++ standard library (STL is an antiquated term, and describes something else) specifies a number of conceptual requirements (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator specifies some of the requirements that `std::vector`s iterators are required to meet).  These requirements amount to an interface (e.g. a set of *operations*) that an iterator is required to support.  None of the requirements specify what *members* an iterator is required to have, nor do they specify accessibility of such members.

Comment: An iterator doesn't have to be a class type either. `T *` is the *archetypical* iterator to a sequence of `T`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are STL's iterators exposing their container's internals?

They don't.

> Why doesn't the standard require the iterators' internals to be private?

Because that would be of no gain. The standard does not specify that the members are publicly accessible and that should be enough to know that you shall not write code that assumes the members are publicly accessible.

If you are working with an implementation where those members are public and you do access them then you are relying on implementation details and your code is not portable.